# Reset default $PATH variable MacOS 12

Tags: bash, macos, path

I'm using macOS 12 Monterey and bash shell.

**.bash_profile**

```
#Default PATH entries
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Applications/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Applications/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Applications/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Applications/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<



# Added by Toolbox App
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mah_prince/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

**.bash_profile.bak**

```
echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/mah_prince/.bash_profile
    eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Applications/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Applications/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Applications/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Applications/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

When I type ***echo $PATH*** it returns

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:"/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";
```

A lot of mac commands are also not available like ***which*** . Also, my installed nodejs, npm are not available.

But if I type

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then the PATH is set and also all the commands are available again.

But if I restart the laptop, the PATH is again reset to the previous path and the commands are also not available again, and also my nodejs.

Comment: Paste code as text not images.

Comment: I would answer if I could copy/paste from the code, but I can't do that from an image.

Comment: Get rid of the part of the `export PATH` line starting with `eval`. And in the following lines, you only need one copy of the `eval` command, not 6 of them.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano please check now.

Comment: @Barmar please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mah_prince/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

to

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/mah_prince/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"

eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

The `eval` command should be on a separate line.

I suspect your `.bash_profile` didn't end in a newline, and the tool that added the `eval` command doesn't check for this, so it added it at the end of the line instead of the next line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! For this problem I couldn't run my react, nodejs projects. Now everything is working just fine.